# How can I rearrange pane layout in Rstudio, making the added source column in the middle?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm now using Rstudio-2022.07.2-Build572. I know that I can add new source column in `Preference -> Pane Layout`, but the added column is always on the left of the screen and cannot be moved.

Is there a way to make the new added source column in the middle of the three columns, so it is more convenient to focus on the center of the screen?

FYI,
Rstudio-2022.07.2-Build572
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS 13.0.1

Comment: From what I can see, this is currently not an available option.  It's been raised with Rstudio (back in 2020) but I can't see any response.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen Oh that's too bad, it could be handful. Still hope some genius guy could find a way to make it :p